# Turn a function into a generator function with no parameters

Tags: python, generator

I am new to Python and having trouble wrapping my head around converting the following function into a generator function that doesn't take any parameters (without importing itertools). The idea is to generate an infinite look-and-say sequence starting with 2, 12, 1112, 3112...and so on. As it is now, the sequence is working, but I'm not quite sure where I need to change my returns to yields or how to do it without taking a parameter (getting rid of (n)). Any help would be appreciated!

```
def count_sequence(n):
    if (n == 1):
        return "2"
    if (n == 2):
        return "12"
    x = "12"
    for i in range (3, n + 1):
        x += "$"
        l = len(x)
        count = 1
        temp = ""
        for y in range(1, l):
            if (x[y] != x[y - 1]):
                temp += str(count + 0)
                temp += x[y - 1]
                count = 1
            else:
                count += 1
        x = temp
    return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a wrapper around your function:

```
def my_generator():
    value = 1
    while True:
        result = count_sequence(value)
        yield result
        value += 1
```

then in-line the definition of `count_sequence`, replacing `return` with `yield` and `n` with `value`. (In this case, I skip a step and also yield the return value directly, rathe than assigning it to `result` first then using `yield result` once at the bottom of the `while` loop.)

```
def my_generator():
    value = 1
    while True:
        if value == 1:
            yield "2"
        elif value == 2:
            yield "12"
        else:
            x = "12"
            for i in range(3, value+1):
                x += "$"
                l = len(x)
                count = 1
                temp = ""
                for y in range(1, l):
                    if x[y] != x[y-1]:
                        temp += str(count)
                        temp += x[y-1]
                        count = 1
                    else:
                        count += 1
                x = temp
             yield x
         value += 1
```

Then you can simplify it a little, for example pulling the first two `yield` expression statements out of the loop and getting rid of the `if` statement.

```
def my_generator():
    yield "2"
    yield "12"
    value = 3
    while True:
        x = "12"
        for i in range(3, value+1):
            x += "$"
            l = len(x)
            count = 1
            temp = ""
            for y in range(1, l):
                if x[y] != x[y-1]:
                    temp += str(count)
                    temp += x[y-1]
                    count = 1
                else:
                    count += 1
            x = temp
         yield x
         value += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your count_sequence() method is called like this:

```
count_sequence(1)
count_sequence(2)
count_sequence(3)
...
```

As a generator the function would look like this:

```
def count_sequence():
  yield "2"
  yield "12"
  x = "12"
  n = 2
  while True:
    n += 1
    for i in range (3, n + 1):
      x += "$"
      l = len(x)
      count = 1
      temp = ""
      for y in range(1, l):
        if (x[y] != x[y - 1]):
          temp += str(count + 0)
          temp += x[y - 1]
          count = 1
        else:
          count += 1
      x = temp
    yield x
```

`n` is a variable now tracked within the generator function.

Call the generator with:

```
my_generator = count_sequence()
next(my_generator)
next(my_generator)
next(my_generator)
...
```